# Scala, Cats and Couchbase - how to connect these 3 things together?

Tags: scala, couchbase, scala-cats

I create an application where I would like to use `Couchbase` as db. I have done a research , but I did not find any good source of knowledge how to use `Couchbase` with `Cats` and `Scala`. The only thing is http://reactivecouchbase.org/ but it looks like to use `Actors` from `Akka`. Also on typelevel there is no docs about cats and couchbase. 
Another thing I have learned is `Doobie`, but it could be use only with relational databases.

My question is - Do I need to use pure, Java code style do connect with Couchbase or is there any kind of tutorials or other sources to learn `Cats` and `Couchbase` together?

Comment: I'm not aware of any connector for Scala connector, but the standard Java SDK supports  RXJava. I'm also not familiar with reactiveCouchbase, but the last commit was more than a year ago.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is why I'm asking about it, because it looks like I will need to use pure Java to connect with couchbase.

Comment: There will almost certainly not be any tutorials for learning Cats and Couchbase together. If you're not already familiar with Cats, you might instead go halfway and try to write the Couchbase calls you need with standard Scala but in the functional style

Comment: Probably I will. I do not need a lot of Cats to use Couchbase.

Comment: Hi, Couchbase Scala dev here.  First, I'm happy to report that the native Scala SDK for Couchbase is nearly complete.  Second, I'd be very interested to see what kind of Cats support you'd like to see?  There won't be any Cats support initially - it's a big library and I'd like to keep the dependencies lean - but we could certainly look at an add-on library if there's good use-cases.  Let us know!

Comment: @GrahamPople nice to hear it. I think there is no need for me to integrate cats with couchbase api, but I hope it will works fine together. Could you tell when this SDK will be available to use or you have any docs which could be seen now?

Comment: Please see https://docs.couchbase.com/scala-sdk/1.0alpha/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html for the initial alpha release.  Caveats apply: this an early release mainly for developers to get an idea of where we're headed, and it's not suitable for production use.  All feedback is greatly appreciated, and the best place to raise it is the forums: https://forums.couchbase.com/.